# If I pickle a string in Python myself, can unpickling it ever be dangerous?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, security, pickle

Say we have a Postgres 12 database that has a table called `MyClass` that has a Text column called `notes`. Users have the ability to save whatever they wish in this notes field. For the purpose of this question, let's assume that they have somehow bypassed all data sanitation.

Could the following lines of code ever be dangerous due to malicious text in obj.notes?

```
import pickle
# (obj is a Python3 instance of MyClass using the Django ORM, so obj.notes is always represented as a unicode string)
obj = MyClass.objects.get(id=1)
pickled = pickle.dumps(obj.notes)
unpickled = pickle.loads(pickled)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python pickle protocol (version 4) serialises strings as: a token, followed by the length of the string, followed by the utf-8 encoded content. The token is a code which marks that the data is to be interpreted as a string (and specifies the data size of the intervening integer). So in theory, all of the encoded string data will be copied directly into the new string object without being parsed (giving no opportunity for the content of the string to influence the behavior of the unpickler machine).

This means even a malicious string should still pickle and unpickle with no change, and has no opportunity to hijack the unpickler machine and run arbitrary code (unlike if the pickled-data itself had been compromised).

```py
import pickle, pickletools
pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps("Hello World"))
```

For details see [pickletools comments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pickletools.py).

Earlier (protocol version 0) instead of specifying a fixed length, the protocol used a delimiter to terminate the string, and expected escaping to be applied (in case the same delimiter was intended to also occur within the string). Alternatively, even with the existing protocol, you could re-implement the pickler to perform string compression of repeating sequences. Either way, the safety depends on the implementation of your pickle library being free of bugs.

Answer (score -1):

It is extremely dangerous to use pickle files from other sources outside of your control, as pickles can contain code. That code can be just about anything, including shell commands against your system.

Pickling is also not always safe to do as your describing it- taking ORM classes, pickling them, and then unpickling them can result in the new classes not having the properly links to the database sessions.

In the example you have I would save the ID and use that to reload the object from the database. For other things where I want to move data in and out of an app I would recommend the `load_safe` function from pyyaml or the `loads` from json (with the default encoder).

Comment: OP *is* in control of the source and guarantees that it is always a string. Your answer goes into generalities but does not address the specific case. That being said, your advice to either pickle the ID or use a safer method is on point.

Comment: They explicitly said that they wants us to assume that their users have bypassed data sanitization, so I answered the specific case of then not being in control of the data since that is what they asked.

Comment: But it's still a string. Is there a string that will ever pickle to something that won't unpickle to the same string?

Comment: The pickle "loads" function stands for "load from string". It takes a string, deserializes it using the pickle protocol, and then creates the objects that the string represents. So the user can provide a string that contains malicious code, and when the pickle loads function is called that code will run. Since pickle can be used to store functions and actual code this isn't even difficult to do- [the pickle documentation page itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) has a giant red alert at the top of the page to make sure people understand this.

Comment: @tedivm: We're not calling `loads` on user input, though. We're calling it on *the result of serializing* user input. The user does not get to provide arbitrary arguments to `loads` directly.

Comment: The attacker has bypassed all sanitation of the content of the `obj.notes` string; they have *not* acquired total control of `pickled`. `pickled` still comes from `pickle.dumps(obj.notes)`, and is safe to unpickle, even if `obj.notes` is malicious.